# Call to a member function getNamedItem() on null

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to make a tool that will get the time someone needs to work. The login is secured with an CSRF token so I need to get that first before I can login.

This is the script what i'm using at the moment:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

  $username = "jules.kreutzer";
  $password = "jules";
  $url = "planner.a-mac.nl";
  $cookie= "koekje.txt";
  $ch = curl_init();

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, '/tmp/'.$cookie);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, '/tmp/'.$cookie);

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  $response = curl_exec($ch);

  if (curl_errno($ch)) die(curl_error($ch));
  $doc = new DOMDocument();
  $doc->loadHTML("http://planner.a-mac.nl");
  $token = $doc->getElementByID("signin__csrf_token")->attributes->getNamedItem("value")->value;
  print_r($token);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

  $params = array(
    'signin[username]' => $username,
    'signin[password]' => $password,
    'signin[_csrf_token]' => $token
  );
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($params));

  curl_exec($ch);

  if (curl_errno($ch)) print curl_error($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
?>
```

When I load this code in my webbrowser I get the following errors:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test.php on line 22
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function getNamedItem() on null in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test.php on line 22

line 22 is:

```
  $token = $doc->getElementByID("signin__csrf_token")->attributes->getNamedItem("value")->value;
```

I was hoping someone could help me get the token so I can use it for the login.

Answer (score 0):

You misspelled getElementById:

Change:

```
$token = $doc->getElementByID("signin__csrf_token")->attributes->getNamedItem("value")->value;
```

to:

```
$token = $doc->getElementById("signin__csrf_token")->attributes->getNamedItem("value")->value;
```

Comment: Nope, that doesn't change anything. I still got the same error.

Comment: Make sure that there is element with id of exactly this value: `signin__csrf_token`

Comment: I did, this is some code from the website where the login screen is located: `<input type="hidden" name="signin[_csrf_token]" value="116f6fd46901f2ff663a29573d4f25e1" id="signin__csrf_token">`

Comment: How did you get the error, I only got the error messages

Comment: I see it in console in Firebug